# PHP LDAP AD Login

Tags: php, formularios, directorioactivo, ldap

Estoy intentando formular un Login con LDAP en PHP y no me conecta al dominio y no se en que fallo.

Hice un dominio nuevo para hacer pruebas por eso los nombres seran visibles ya que es solo una prueba

Nombre Equipo Win Server: WIN-OLN6KSATODL
Dominio: sena.com

Código

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

$adServer = "ldap://WIN-OLN6KSATODL.sena.com";

$ldap = ldap_connect($adServer);
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$ldaprdn = 'sena' . "\\" . $username;

ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

$bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $ldaprdn, $password);


if ($bind) {
    $filter="(sAMAccountName=$username)";
    $result = ldap_search($ldap,"dc=sena,dc=com",$filter);
    ldap_sort($ldap,$result,"389");
    $info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
    for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++)
    {
        if($info['count'] > 1)
            break;
        echo "<p>You are accessing <strong> ". $info[$i]["sn"][0] .", " . $info[$i]["givenname"][0] ."</strong><br /> (" . $info[$i]["samaccountname"][0] .")</p>\n";
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($info);
        echo '</pre>';
        $userDn = $info[$i]["distinguishedname"][0]; 
    }
    @ldap_close($ldap);
} else {
    $msg = "Invalid email address / password";
    echo $msg;
}

}else{
?>
<form action="#" method="POST">
    <label for="username">Username: </label><input id="username" type="text" name="username" /> 
    <label for="password">Password: </label><input id="password" type="password" name="password" />        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Comprueba que te puedes conectar a traves de Telnet: telnet hostldap puerto Luego bajate LDAPExplorer y intenta establecer conexión, sino puedes es por que necesitas mas datos de DN

Comment: ¿Cual es el error que obtienes Alberto?